# Passing on a session from one website to another

Tags: c#

How can i pass on a session from one http request to another with c#?

I am not using asp just c#.

For example, this is my script : http://pastebin.com/cGXcRRMK

Okay so. When it connects to http://insanityflyff.com/account.php it logs in perfectly, Then i need it to connect to the next one with the same session that was used to log in with, the next one is the http://insanityflyff.com/ajax.php?a=vote&submit='1' one.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: SQL Server Session State Provider    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx

Comment: How does that work? its not related with c# is it?

Comment: you should configure it in the web.config file first, google it

Comment: It can be normally its part of ASP.Net but you can use the framework on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close - assuming that the session is maintained by setting a cookie, you need to make sure that *all* of the requests use the *same* `CookieContainer`, rather than setting up a new one for each request. Make it a parameter to the post method, or a field in the class, or use some other way to share it around.

e.g.:

```
private static CookieContainer cookies;

public static string Post(string url, string data)
{
   string vystup = null;

   try
   {
       //SNIP other bits of setup

       if(cookies==null)
       {
          cookies = new CookieContainer();
       }
       WebReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
```